# Eclipse osx, no matching constructor

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am pretty sure my code is correct in terms of the arguments I am inputting to my function however on eclipse I am getting an error that there is no matching constructor. I was wondering if I need to change a setting in eclipse (it seems quite fiddly to get C++ to work so far on mac) or if there is an error in my code. So the code is a linked list of objects I have a node class which is then included in the linked list class.

the node constructor

```
Node::Node(Animal& a) : animal(a), next(0) {
}
```

then I call it in the linked list like this

```
void LinkedList::addAtIndex(const Animal& a, int index) {
Node *nodeToAdd = new Node(a);
```

the line above gives me an error no matching constructor for initialization of Node

Comment: You probably want `Node::Node(const Animal& a)`.

Comment: When asking questions regarding build errors, please always include the *actual* error you get. Copy-paste the complete error output you get, as text, in full and without any editing. Also include any possible informational notes as well. And if possibly, try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to include as well, with comments where the errors are.

Comment: sorry i thought typing out the error was acceptable but I will remember to copy paste the error next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that context:

```
void LinkedList::addAtIndex(const Animal& a, int index) {
   Node *nodeToAdd = new Node(a);
```

`a` is expected to be constant. You're passing it to a constructor where you try to use the non-constant reference, thus violating the const contract/qualifier => can't do.

To fix that: `Node::Node(const Animal& a) : animal(a), next(0)`

if your member `animal` is not a non-const reference to `Animal` this will work, else you'll have to do the other way: remove the const qualifier from the `addAtIndex` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct with constness.

You probably want

```
Node::Node(const Animal& a) : animal(a), next(0) {}
```

or

```
void LinkedList::addAtIndex(Animal& a, int index) {
    Node *nodeToAdd = new Node(a);
    // ..
}
```

as const-reference cannot bind to non-const-reference.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the constructor of node to take a const animal

```
    Node::Node(const Animal& a) : animal(a), next(0)
```

and everything worked fine